# How to make an element stop scrolling after an certain point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to replicate a part of [this](http://1qbit.com/) page, if you scroll down a bit you see a picture of a graph and some text.
Does anyone know how they did the scrolling effect on the photo and text? And the text appears after a certain point, how did they do that?

Comment: This would be a parallax no ? Have you tried anything yet ? By the way that site is using : http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/

Comment: You could try using skrollr.js. https://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/ short story, they set a position relative to the the div that contains the text/image as a kind of event trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there are two questions being asked here. One being how to only display items once they are already within the viewport, and the other being how to apply a parallax effect.

For displaying items only once they are within viewport, ScrollReveal looks like a tool that would took the trick. You can check it out here:
https://scrollrevealjs.org/

As for the parallax effect, I made a super lightweight Javascript class that you can use. Check out the source code here:

http://codepen.io/rodomeista/pen/vGqWXr

There are a few things you will need to update in your code to get this working.

1. Copy all of Javascript code into your main JS file.
2. Add the 'parallax-content' class to any items you wish to apply the effect to.
3. Specify the 'parallax-offset' and the 'parallax-axis' attributes on the DOM element in question.

Exampe:

Let's say you were to have an image element that looks like so

```
<img src = "./path/to/image.png" />
```

And I want to apply a subtle parallax effect along the y axis.
All I would need to do is adjust attribute like so:

```
<img src = "./path/to/image.png" class = "parallax-content" data-parallax-offset = "-50" data-parallax-axis = "y" />
```

Now run your code and see it in action! Feel free to play around with the data-parralax-offset number to get the speed right for your needs. I'm happy to answer any questions about the code.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Hey, I have a question. `var translate = function(_amt) {
  _amt = "translate" + dir +  "(" + _amt + "px)";
  var transform = 
   {
    '-webkit-transform':  _amt,
    '-moz-transform':   _amt,
    '-o-transform':    _amt,
    'transform':      _amt
   };
  $i.css(transform);
 };`  What is the "translate" for, in _amt = "translate" + dir +  "(" + _amt + "px)";?

Comment: And what does this part mean? `var update = function(_scroll) {
    var translateAmount = getDistanceFromCenter(_scroll) / viewport.c * buffer;
    translate(translateAmount);
 };

 update(0);
 return {
  update: update
 };`

Comment: So translate is referring to the pixel value that an object is being moved via CSS. You can get a full explanation of CSS transforms [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/).

To answer your second question, the update function takes in a scroll amount and determines the pixel offset of a particular item based on how far it is from the vertical center of the browser window.